# Distribute div objects hopefully

Tags: php, html, css

I want to do a web page which can distribute objects hopefully considering the height and the width of the objects inputted.

In the first page I input the height and the width of the object, the quantity of that object, and a limit per row. And the second page will show the objects distributed.

**Example:**

> object 35x60cm, 3 quantities |  object 60x60cm, 4 quantities |  object
>   70x70cm, 5 quantities  and the limit is 200 cm a row.

The object will have distribute hopefully and when the 200cm per row is reached, another row will be added and the remain objects will situate in the 2nd row, and if the second row is not enough, then it will be a 3rd row, and so on.

Objects will be like divs!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *hopefully*? or.... helpfully?

Comment: Do you use Python? As in, are you meaning to reference the Python distribute tag?

Comment: I want to do it in php, thanks!

Comment: I find your question hard to understand, the "object", can you edit your question and give details as to what the object actually is? As in it's probably not a [programming Object.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: The object is a rectangle and i have to input the size in the first page.

Comment: If you could edit your question to state it's a [div object](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmldiv.php), that will make a lot more sense to people reading this. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish the distribution with CSS and JS only. Here's the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="inputWidth"=> give me width</input>
<input type="text" id="inputHeight"=> give me height</input>
<input type="text" id="inputNum"=> give me number</input>
<input type="text" id="inputContWidth"=> give me container width</input>
<button onclick="addShapes()">Submit</button>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

And the CSS code for the distribution. This is both to distribute the items and to make them visible:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

Then use Javascript to add as many items as needed using the inputs:

```
function addShapes() {
  removeItems();
  var inputWidth = document.getElementById("inputWidth").value;
  var inputHeight = document.getElementById("inputHeight").value;
  var inputNum = document.getElementById("inputNum").value;
  var inputContWidth = document.getElementById("inputContWidth").value;
  document.getElementById("container").style.width = inputContWidth;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputNum; i++) {
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.style.width = inputWidth;
    element.style.height = inputHeight;
    element.className = "item";
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(element);
  }
}

function removeItems() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
  while (elements.length > 0) {
    elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
  }
}
```

And here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/gingerdeadshot/pen/JXZNGX

Comment: I don't know Javascript... Can you do a quick script? Thanks!

Comment: @Kigris Edited. I actually had to learn some Javascript in the process.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, but it doesn't seem to work... I mean the container width doesn't matter like i see, and i can't identify the objects inididually like colors or ids! And i would need more inputs, like 20 or 30... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kigris You can add as many inputs as necessary using the framework I gave you. Stack Overflow is not a crowdsourced dev team that will code your work for you. It's a platform to help you figure out how to do it on your own.

Comment: I don't know much about php and javascript, so your comment doesn't make sense. Thanks anyway!